# Android emulator on Eclipse

Tags: android, android-emulator

I have eclipse up and running and am currently in the middle of developing my first app, but the emulator doesn't seem to work properly when I want to test my progress. I am running Windows 7 and I have installed the ADT, SDK etc.

When I click run, the emulator starts up and a command prompt seems to appear very quickly on and off. Then the emulator window opens with just an Android logo on it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Be patient :). The emulator takes a long time to start. So, when you see that Android Logo, go have a cup of tea and come back, and hopefully it will be up and running.

On a side note, once the emulator is up and running, you don't have to close it each time. If you have to modify your app, go back to eclipse, make the modification, and re-run the app. It will re-use the same emulator instance, and this time, it will be much faster.

It is just the initialization of emulator that takes a long time.

Answer (score 0):

I cant speak for the Windows 7 side. However, so long as the emulator is loaded with the Android logo on the display, then it will probably just take some time.

I use Ubuntu, and it can take 5+ minutes for the Emulator to start properly.

Answer (score 0):

Its just because of the loading of the Android sdk in to that adb (Emulator).
Keep patient. . and wait for some minutes it will autometicaly show the Android Device Home Screen soon after geting start.

If it takes to much time then you need to increase the ram size of the emulator.
So Keep patient and if still it happend then let me know.
Thanks.